How to say these two distinct functions have the same structure?
Yesterday, I posted this question, which remains unanswered. In this related question, I ask a different yet more precise question that may help me solve the other question.
Let $N=\{1,2\}$ be a two-player set.
First, let $A_2=\{x,y\}$ be a two-alternative set, let $\mathcal{P}(A_2)$ be the set of all linear orders profiles on $A_2$, and let $d^1_2:\mathcal{P}(A_2)\to A_2$ be player $1$'s dictatorship (namely, the function that selects the alternative in $A_2$ that is top-ranked by player $1$ at every linear order profile on $A_2$).
Now, let $A_3=\{x,y,z\}$ be a three-alternative set, let $\mathcal{P}(A_3)$ be the set of all linear orders profiles on $A_3$, and let $d^1_3:\mathcal{P}(A_3)\to A_3$ be player $1$'s dictatorship (namely, the function that selects the alternative in $A_3$ that is top-ranked by player $1$ at every linear order profile on $A_3$).
It is clear that the functions $d_2^1$ and $d_3^1$ are different functions, since they have different domain and codomain. However, there is a sense in which these two functions are almost the same function, since they both have the same structure. I have spent the last day reading about different types of morphisms, but I can't figure out which is the specific morphism that relates the functions $d_2^1$ and $d_3^1$.
So, my question is two-fold:

What type of morphism (if any!) defines the relationship between the functions $d_2^1$ and $d_3^1$?
How can I formally state that the functions $d_2^1$ and $d_3^1$ preserve the same structure?


The sense is that you can give a uniform definition of the function that doesn't depend on the number of alternatives. I think this is related to what computer scientists call "parametric polymorphism," and often it can be described in terms of something being a natural transformation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation).

Thank you very much. I do really appreciate the guidance—I had never heard of this concept before.

@QiaochuYuan I have been playing with the definition you gave in your answer, but it does not really work for my purposes. I have also been trying to formalise what the idea I described in my question using the notion of a natural transformation, but I don’t seem to get it right. Could you please expand on your “natural transformation” approach? How can I use natural transformations to define what I want to define? Any help will be much appreciated.

It is possible to phrase this in very abstract terms along the lines I indicted in my comment but I think that would obscure the underlying idea. Here's a simple definition that I think captures the intuition:
Say that the reduction of a voting rule on an alternative set $\{ x_1, \dots x_{n+1} \}$ of size $n+1$ to a voting rule on an alternative set $\{ x_1, \dots x_n \}$ of size $n$ is the voting rule obtained by restricting our attention to preference profiles in which every voter ranks $x_{n+1}$ last. For this definition to work we need to disallow perverse voting rules like "anti-dictatorship" (select the alternative that voter $1$ ranked last), to ensure that if every voter ranks $x_{n+1}$ last then $x_{n+1}$ is never selected; I assume there are standard definitions in your literature that do that.
Then $d_1^2$ is the reduction of $d_1^3$. You can use this to give a definition of what it means for a collection of voting rules $d_n$ on $n$-element alternative sets to be "consistent with each other": it should mean that, for all $n$, $d_n$ is the reduction of $d_{n+1}$. How does that sound?

Thank you very much for your thoughtful answer. Your suggestion seems promising, but I need a definition that works for all voting rules (not only dictatorships, and not excluding anti-dictatorships a priori). I only want to exclude funny voting rules that change their structure when the alternative set changes its size.

@EoD: this seems trickier. I think I can write down a definition for voting rules which return as output a linear ordering on the alternative set (you just take the above definition but delete $x_{n+1}$ from the output) but it's not clear to me what to do if voting rules return as output an element of the alternative set.

Thank you for your comment. I understand it’s a tough problem that may not even have a reasonable solution. In my mind, it is kind of intuitive to require that a voting rule should keep its structure regardless of the size of the alternative set; but I have no clue how to formalise that apparently simple idea. In case it helps, the paper I’m basing my work on is Koray (Econometrica, 2000), who makes no assumption of this sort because his axioms imply this “invariance” property that I would like to assume (rather than derive).

@EoD: in other contexts there are good formalizations of what that means in terms of natural transformations, as I mentioned above. But here there appears to me to be a technical difficulty with your specific setup (which I don't want to spell out in detail). You can resolve it by altering the definition of a voting rule in a couple of different ways. One way or another you need a way to compare voting rules over different sets and the above or a variation of it seems to me like the most straightforward way to do that.
